# How to save textfield data in dictionary and then in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsdictionary

Once a user finished entering text in a UITextfield I wand the data to be in a dictionary first and then the dictionary added to array. But for some reason after inserting into array .. It logs null..

**.h**

```
 @interface Bread_TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{    
    NSMutableArray * inventoryarray;
}

**.m**

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Make sure to set the label to have a ta
    NSString*textfieldclicked;

    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        textfieldclicked=@"Unit";
    } else if (textField.tag ==2) {
        textfieldclicked=@"Case";

    }

    id textFieldSuper = textField;

    while (![textFieldSuper isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

        textFieldSuper = [textFieldSuper superview];

    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)textFieldSuper];

    InventoryTableViewCell *cell = (InventoryTableViewCell *)[self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSMutableDictionary * productinfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [productinfo setObject:cell.product.text forKey:@"product"];
    [productinfo setObject:textField.text forKey:textfieldclicked];

     NSLog(@"productin %@", productinfo);      
    [inventoryarray addObject: productinfo];

}

-(IBAction)save{

    NSLog(@"array %@", inventoryarray);

}
```

Comment: dude , where ur alloc-init ?

Comment: just fixed that....  however my array only shows one dictionary at a time.. :/

Comment: pls have a look on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. alloc-init the array in which you want to add your objects.
2. do alloc-init of your dictionary outside the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method and where it scope it visible might be in `viewDidLoad`

like

```
       @interface yourViewController ()
            @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * product info;

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.productinfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-visible cells **do not actually exist**.  Only the visible ones plus one outside the screen at each end are actually in memory. The other ones are created when you scroll and their data is pulled from the data source.
As soon as a cell is pushed out of the screen (+1 cell) it will be removed from the hierarchy and added to the reuse pool.

**TL;DR:** You can't loop through out-of-screen cells since they don't exist. If you want to access the data for each item, do it in your data source.

Comment: When a cell is off screen it won't necessarily be deallocated but it will be removed from the view hierarchy and added to the cell reuse pool. Slightly pedantic I know. Good answer & upvoted.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to reflect your comment. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply.. not sure what you mean by data source in this case... because i need to grab the text that the user entered in textfield in the cells.

Comment: Then you can't. Make sure to save your user input in an array somewhere before the cell scrolls out. Or you may loose the data.

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField but don't know how to access the name of the textfield because i have two of them. and want to differentiate them.. know which one a user entered text in..

Comment: Set a tag on your textfields in your storyboard and use textField.tag to differentiate them.

Comment: thank you.. now my problem.. is the array not saving any of my dictionary. data.  I revised my code in the question.  Not sure why its not working.. maybe missing something.